# Download Excel file from Firefox using Selenium

Tags: selenium

How to download an Excel file from the web using Selenium? I tried using `firefoxprofile.setpreference`, but it's not working to me.

Here is my code:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",downloadPath);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml");
driver firefoxdriver=new firefoxdriver(firefoxProfile)
```

I am using Windows 7 and Firefox 39.0.

Still during execution Firefox opens a window to ask if I want to save or open the file, with open selected by default.

Is there a solution for this issue?